# Magento 2.2.4: SEO issue - Homepage Search Results in "No information is available for this page."

Tags: magento2, seo, sitemaps, google

I have recently replatformed from a custom PHP build to Magento 2.2.4, during the go-live process we changed from www to non-www versions of the site.  I've updated Search Console to make the preference to the non-www version of the site.

Now I'm getting the following notice:

[image]

Magento is using a stock version of the robots.txt file as seen here [current robots.txt](https://witsendmosaic.com/robots.txt)

Everything within Google says the root domain is able to be indexed: 
[image]

The default domain is also not www it's the non-www version. 
[image]

I also verified that the site has Index,Follow enabled.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this maybe occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's something in the robots.txt

You could just delete it as it will not hurt anything to have it or not have it.

People think the robots.txt makes a difference in SEO - only if you have robotted out pages you want indexed. Otherwise it makes no difference on 99.9% of sites. So delete it and fetch in SC - that should go away.

Comment: I thought about that, I just wish I knew the cause.  Everything on the old site ended with *.php so I was thinking it was that entry, but it wouldn’t surprise me if it was a bug either.  If I were to try removing things slowly what should I try first?

Comment: It's one step, delete this: https://witsendmosaic.com/robots.txt

Who knows what line in there is causing this, as Magento likely is auto generating any part of your page in any number of these robotted out sections.

Is your site like a million pages? If no, just delete it, you don't need to robot out anything.

Comment: It's about 15k pages, I'm just nervous as the business has an "SEO guy" and he'll probably have his way if I don't figure out the reason why it's being blocked and removing the robots.txt might make him uncomfortable.

Comment: I removed everything that was not a folder, or a specific directive and requested a fetch in SC.  If this doesn't work, I'll remove the robots.txt entirely.  :crosses_fingers:

Comment: Submit the new robots txt in search console and fetch the index page and you should see the change right away if there is one.

Trust me, the robots txt on  a 15k block is NOTHING.. SEOs hold on to this as an illusion of what is important in SEO, it's really not. I am doing an online SEO 101 course Thursday i can explain more then.

Comment: Thanks, @josh.  Within Search Console, the page fetched correctly with stock robots.txt.  I think what happened is that the old site, had all URLs ending in .php, and Magento's default robots.txt blocks URLs including .php.   So I think the updated robots.txt blocked already indexed URLs and the new page couldn't be viewed because Google still thought the site had .php in the URL even though it no longer did.  I believe this blocked the page from being indexed.

Comment: Great! I'm glad I was able to help :)